How to Create a Calendar Grid in SwiftUI Where Each Month Has Correct Number of Days and Empty Cells for Invalid Dates?
I am trying to create a dynamic calendar in SwiftUI, where I display each month with the correct number of days, starting from the correct weekday (e.g., December 1st should be under Thursday). The days of the month should be laid out correctly, and if there are leftover spaces (for invalid dates like April 31st), they should be shown as empty cells.
What I'm trying to achieve:

Display each month with the correct number of days.
For example, a month like February should have 28 or 29 days, April should have 30, and months like January, March, May, etc., should have 31.

Align each day under the correct weekday.
For example, if December 1st is a Thursday, it should be the first item in the grid under Thursday. If the month starts mid-week, the days should be aligned accordingly.

Handle invalid dates like April 31st.
The day that exceeds the valid range for the month (like April 31st) should be left as an empty cell in the calendar grid.


4.Include blank spaces for days before the 1st of the month or after the last day.
For instance, if the month starts on a Tuesday, the first row should have Monday, Tuesday, and some empty cells before the 1st appears.
My current approach:
I have the following code for creating a calendar cell, but I am struggling with how to dynamically create the correct number of days for each month, align them under the correct weekdays, and leave empty spaces for invalid dates.
struct CalendarCell: View {
    let group: GroupT
    @EnvironmentObject var dateHolder: DateHolder
    @StateObject var eventViewModel: EventViewModel
    let count: Int
    let startingSpaces: Int
    let daysInMonth: Int
    let daysInPrevMonth: Int
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    @State private var isShowingDailyEventPage = false
    @State private var isLoading = false

    var body: some View {
        let textColor = self.textColor(type: self.monthStruct().monthType)
        
        VStack {
            // Show day only for current month
            if monthStruct().monthType == .Current {
                Text(monthStruct().day())
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(textColor)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(isLoading ? Color.gray.opacity(0.2) : Color.clear)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .overlay(
                        Group {
                            if textColor == .black {
                                Button(action: {
                                    fetchDailyEvents()
                                    isShowingDailyEventPage = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                        .imageScale(.small)
                                        .padding(4)
                                }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDailyEventPage) {
                                    DailyEventPage(date: dateForCell(), group: group, events: events, eventViewModel: eventViewModel)
                                        .onAppear {
                                            fetchDailyEvents()
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        alignment: .topTrailing
                    )
                
                // Event indicator if events are present
                if !events.isEmpty {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 6, height: 6)
                        .padding(.top, 2)
                }
            }

            // Show loading indicator
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView("Loading Events...")
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to fetch events
    func fetchDailyEvents() {
        isLoading = true
        let carpoolID = group.carpoolID
        let joinCode = group.joinCode

        eventViewModel.fetchDailyEvents(forCarpoolID: carpoolID.uuidString, date: dateForCell()) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let events):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.events = events
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Error fetching events: \(error)")
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper functions for determining month type and day
    func monthStruct() -> MonthStruct {
        let start = startingSpaces == 0 ? startingSpaces + 7 : startingSpaces
        if count <= start {
            let day = daysInPrevMonth + count - start
            return MonthStruct(monthType: MonthType.Previous, dayInt: day)
        } else if count - start > daysInMonth {
            let day = count - start - daysInMonth
            return MonthStruct(monthType: MonthType.Next, dayInt: day)
        }
        let day = count - start
        return MonthStruct(monthType: MonthType.Current, dayInt: day)
    }

    // Convert day to Date
    private func dateForCell() -> Date {
        let firstOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: dateHolder.date))!
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: monthStruct().dayInt - 1, to: firstOfMonth)!
    }
}

Problem:
I want to make sure each month is displayed with the correct number of days (e.g., April should have 30 days, and February should have 28 or 29), and the days should be aligned under the correct weekdays.
I also want to make sure any invalid dates (like April 31st) appear as empty cells, and all days are correctly placed under their corresponding weekday (e.g., December 25th should be under Wednesday).
What am I missing or doing wrong?
How can I modify my code to achieve the above functionality?

Note, you should have @ObservedObject var eventViewModel: EventViewModel not
@StateObject var eventViewModel: EventViewModel. What errors do you get? What am I missing or doing wrong?, explain what the problem is, not what you want to make sure.

You need an array of day items then put the events into them. Ie don't call monthStruct() from body. SwiftUI needs the data ready before body is called

In the title you mention a grid and this would be a suitable way to solve: try building a LazyVGrid with 7 columns. You could supply it with an array of items that contains dummy entries at start and end (as placeholders for the days in the previous/next month).

The problem is that the calendar cells are not being equally spaced out according to the day. For example if Jan 1st is a monday, it might not always be spaced directly under monday.

Can you guys write down answers with your potential fixes so I can see how they work?

Research CalendarKit
